# How to play next track from Document Directory in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file

I make a simple media player. I have a `UITableViewController` with mp3 files from Document Directory and `UIViewController` which plays mp3 files. I pass `NSURL` of a mp3 file from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` and I can play it. I want to make buttons are which will be turn track to next or previous. How can I make it?

The code is passing NSURL on a specific file.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var nameOfObjectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default it's name and
    var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var wayToFile = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var passMusicFileURL: NSURL? // for pass mp3

    if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
        let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(nameOfObjectForPass)
        println(musicFile)
        passMusicFileURL = musicFile
    }
    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
        playerVC.nameMusicFile = nameOfObjectForPass // name
        playerVC.mp3URL = passMusicFileURL

        // test 
        playerVC.allUrlsVC = allURLS
    }
```

The code is playing mp3 file

```
    func playMusic() {
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil) // == true
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL, error: &error)
   // audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    if currentPause == nil {
    } else {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = currentPause
    }
    //
    audioPlayer.volume = 0.5
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

**UPDATE**

I made following

```
  var arrayMP3url: Array<AnyObject>!

    func playNextSound() {
        var queue = AVQueuePlayer(URL: mp3URL)
        var current = queue.currentItem

        var arrayForSearch = arrayMP3url as! [NSURL]

        var arrNS = arrayForSearch as NSArray

        var index = arrNS.indexOfObject(mp3URL!)
        println("index \(index)")

        println("array for search \(arrayForSearch)")

        println("current song \(current)")
    }
```

But I always get the same index from `NSArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your array of mp3 files, and determine `current playing index` using `indexPath`, increase or, decrease the `current playing index` on button click as `Next, or, Prev`, and change the mp3 file by the index. 
Replay the music.

Simple.

Ping if you need more help.

**Update**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController

    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

    //We only need to pass current index, and array of mp3 urls

    playerVC.curIndex=indexPath.row;
    playerVC.mp3s= listOfMP3Files;

}
```

So as described above, just declare two properties in your `playerVC`, ie

**`curIndex` as int and `mp3s` as NSArray.**

In the function

```
func playMusic() {

    var nameOfObjectForPass = mp3s![curIndex]; // default it's name and
    var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var wayToFile = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var passMusicFileURL: NSURL? // for pass mp3

    if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
        let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(nameOfObjectForPass)
        println(musicFile)
        passMusicFileURL = musicFile
    }

    self.nameMusicFile = nameOfObjectForPass // name
    self.mp3URL = passMusicFileURL

        // test 
    self.allUrlsVC = allURLS

   AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil) // == true
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL, error: &error)
   // audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    if currentPause == nil {
    } else {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = currentPause
    }
    //
    audioPlayer.volume = 0.5
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Then simply define your next and previous index calculations like

```
func playNextSound(){
   self.curIndex++;
   var maxCount=self.mp3s.count-1;
   if(self.curIndex>maxCount){
         self.curIndex=maxCount;
   }

   playMusic();
}

func playPrevSound(){
   self.curIndex--;
   if(self.curIndex<0){
         self.curIndex=0;
   }

   playMusic();
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: I tried get index of current file several method but I don't get the index. I tried

Comment: I made following Pass the var mp3Furl: Array<AnyObject>! (it is array of files from document directory.)
to UIViewController. Then I made var queue = AVQueuePlayer(URL: mp3URL) var current = queue.currentItem that get current file document directory and I can to do it. But when I make     var arrayForSearch = mp3Furl as! [NSURL]  var index = find(arrayForSearch, mp3URL!) I get nil. Please can you show example?

Comment: @Alexsander added code, it might have bug, as I don't know swift much, but logic should be same.